# Hosting rest-api server on aws workspace vs ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, hosting, ngrok, amazon-workspaces

I need to host a service with rest-api on a server which does below listed tasks:

- Download and upload files in s3 bucket
- Run some cpu intensive computations
- Return json response

I know an ec2 instance will be a better approach to host my service but given price differences between workspace and ec2 instance, I am exploring this route. Are there any limitations on amazon workspace that might prevent me from using them for my use case?

I came across [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which I believe can help me direct requests over the internet to my workspace local server.

Has anyone played around with it and could add some suggestion?

Comment: What cost basis are you using to compare the two services? That is, which Amazon EC2 instance type and Workspace type did you select? Are you wanting Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am looking for Linux machine. I need around 32 GB RAM with minimum storage as I will be using S3 bucket for storing my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS terms of service do not allow you to do that I’m afraid. See section 36 on workspaces.

http://aws.amazon.com/service-terms/

> 36.3. You and End Users may only use the WorkSpaces Services for an End User’s personal or office productivity. WorkSpaces are not meant to accept inbound network connections, be used as server instances, or serve web traffic or your network traffic. You may not reconfigure the inbound network connections of your WorkSpaces. We may shut down WorkSpaces that are used in violation of this Section or other provisions of the Agreement.

I suggest you use an r5a.xlarge for the lowest cost 32GB RAM instance type (it’s AMD processor is cheaper than r5 on intel). Investigate whether spot instances would work if your state persists on S3 and not in the local instance, otherwise if you need it for at least a year reserved instances are discounted over on demand pricing.